# How can I add a new commit before a previous commit?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

I created a new branch, then I created one new commit on this new branch. Now, I want create a new commit that will be before the previous commit. And I don't want to change the previous commit.

How can I do it in a simple way?

Comment: It's slightly unclear: you have a branch (starting at some commit, "A"), and you have added a commit "B". Now, you want to insert a new commit ("C"), but do you want it to be before "A" or to be before "B"?

Also, when you are finished, do you want the final state of the repository to be the same as it is now (i.e. you're "splitting" the current commit), or to contain all the changes from "B" and "C" (just inserting new changes earlier in the history).

Comment: @Jelaby No. I have a branch strating at some commit, "A". and I want to add new commit "B" that will be before "A". And so I will get: B and then A.

Comment: Even if someone can actually answer HOW to do it, it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you cannot insert a commit in front of another and have the second keep its original SHA. However, the changes applied by the second commit *can* be unchanged.

I think you have two choices:

### Create a commit after the current one, then reorder them

1. Make you changes and commit them
2. `git rebase -i` and reorder the commits

This has the advantage that you can always `git rebase --abort` to get back to a clean state where all your commits are available. On the other hand, if your two commits touch the same bit of code, you will be applying your new change to the current state of the code, and then will have to re-write it for the previous state; this might or might not turn out to be complicated.

### Use `git-rebase -i` and `break` and create a new change before the first one

1. `git rebase -i`. Insert a new line containing just `break` to the start of the change list
2. Git will stop at the point you said "break", so before any changes were applied. You can make the changes you need. Commit your changes (you may wish to note down the commit SHA, so that you can easily reapply these changes if the next step goes wrong).
3. `git rebase --continue`. Your existing commit will be added on top of the current one. There may be conflicts to resolve.

This has the advantage that you'll be making your changes when your working directly is in the state you expect it to be.

It has the disadvantage that if there are conflicts in the second commit, you can't just use `git rebase --abort` to get back to a safe place as it will lose your new commit. If you did remember to note down the commit SHA of your new change, you can start from step 1 again, and do `git cherry-pick THE-SHA` to get your changes back for step 2.

Comment: `git rebase -i` (plain and simple) will not permit creation of a new initial commit.

Comment: @matt OP has created a new branch, presumably from another branch. We're not talking about the first commit in the whole repository, but a new commit *on their branch*.

Comment: I updated the original question for clarity here.